# How to quickly query multiple collections in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Foo, Bar and Baz are all Mongoid collection models. There are the only collections in the DB.

Is there a more efficient way to get all the data in the DB?

```
Foo.all + Bar.all + Baz.all
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's not such thing like a table in MongoDB. There is however, `collections` which might be seen as the inverse of a table in a RDBMS.

Comment: Yes, I meant collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of querying several collections at the time, and I believe that if one try to do that will defeat the purpose of using a NONSQL DB like MongoDB.

However, there is one way of archiving this behaviour in MongoDB. Using embedded documents. For example:

```
class Everything
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embeds_many :foos, class_name: 'Foo',  inverse_of: :everything
    embeds_many :bars, class_name: 'Bar',  inverse_of: :everything
    embeds_many :bazs, class_name: 'Bazs', inverse_of: :everything

end

class Foo
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :foo, type: String

    embedded_in :everything, class_name: 'Everything', inverse_of: :foos
end

class Bar
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :bar, type: String

    embedded_in :everything, class_name: 'Everything', inverse_of: :bars
end

class Bazs
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :baz, type: String

    embedded_in :everything, class_name: 'Everything', inverse_of: :bazs
end
```

Doing `Everything.all` will retrieve all documents in `Everything` along with all the embedded documents in one call.